# ASP.NET MVC. How render a Partial with no model (like create view)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial

I would like to render partial like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartial")
```

However my partial does need a typed object, for instance: MyPartial.cshtml :

```
@model MyApplication.Models.MyClass
(...)
```

But I would like to render it on my view **WITHOUT a initialized model, like a "Create" view.**

> Create views is bound to a model, but is initialized empty.

What I already tried:

`@Html.Partial("_MyPartial")`  The main view model is passed to the partial and it throws an incompatible types error.

`@Html.Partial("_MyPartial", null)` throws same error.

`@Html.Partial("_MyPartial", new MyClass())`  initializes view with default values. I don't want pre initialized view.

In a "Create" view, no model is passed to the view, BUT the view is bound to a model. I would like to render this partial in a "create" view. It must no be bound to a initialized model instance. It must be initialized empty.

Comment: "I don't want pre initialized view" - what exactly do you mean by that? If you want something other than what your default constructor supplies, use an object initializer.

Comment: He doesn't want default values in input boxes such as a `0` in an input for an `int` property of his model, similar to `return View();` vs `return View(model);` in a Create controller action.

Comment: It sounds like you might be misusing the mvc pattern. Do you have a use case? You can have a base view with no model and subclass from there, however, you cannot have a view bound to a model and then pass nothing that view.

Comment: I'm using for complementing the "create" view. Some of this partial are added dynamically by ajax.

Comment: This is a relevant question. I want to do the same. Did you figured it out? @DanielSantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fact, this is not possible, cause partial gets the model from the main view, if there is no one from itself.

In this case you must initialize the call partial and pass not only the model as `null` but the entire data from the context must be cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

You have already write code to accept model type in view:

```
@model MyApplication.Models.MyClass
```

So it is compulsory that you have to pass model in view.

If you don't wants to use model then remove your code which accept model

Comment: your comment does not apply to "Create" views, where no model is passed to the view, BUT the view is bound to a model. I would like to render this partial in a "create" view. It must no be bound to a initialized model instance. It must be initialized empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use html.renderaction instead of doing partial [like this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-action-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc/) and dont declare any model for the view, if it really dont use one in the first place?

Oh yeah return a partialview in the action return and dont forget the curly braces after @ sign, it matters

Answer (score 0):

When you want to return a partialview with no model. Use this.

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Your partial view") }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".